# Display an object on specific position of an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bitmap and I'm trying to show a user control object on a specific position(based on X and Y) of that bitmap  image, Do you have any solution?

actually I have used map file with the specific extension(*.ECW).
also I could add ellipse or draw an image in the specific position but I would add a specific component (for a example a button that created as a user Control).
sorry for this unexecutable code . assume we have a graphic object that a picture or map placed on as a background . 
now we have to add a component to specific point .
I have drawn  an ellipse like this

```
ImageLayout BackgroundImageLayout;
protected Bitmap Background;
int  ppiRadius =100;

Background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
// Set up the map bitmap
// Get a graphics obejct for the bitmap
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Background);
graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 0, 0, 
                          Width, Height);
// Draw the layers to the bitmap
var hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
if (_allLayersHandle != null)
    {
     foreach (var v in _allLayersHandle)
     {
     LastError = GlobalMapperDLL.GM_DrawLayer(hdc, v.Value, 
    ref _currentViewRect, 0, 0,

     Background.Width, Background.Height);
                }
            }
 graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc); 
 if (LastError != GlobalMapperDLL.GM_Error_t32.GM_Error_None) return;

 _centerPoint = GISConvert.GetCenterPixel();
 graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;                
 var point = GISConvert.LatLonToPixel(sitePosition);      
  graphics.DrawEllipse(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 2), new RectangleF((point.X - ppiRadius / 2), (point.Y - ppiRadius / 2), ppiRadius, ppiRadius));
//or  graphics.DrawImage
```

Comment: It seems unclear what you want to do. Do you mean like making a pop-up/tooltip appear at the mouse cursor, upon a specific action? Maybe try to add the code you already have, but with a comment where you want to do stuff.

Comment: You can use a [`Canvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netframework-4.8) which allows absolute positioning. The attached properties can be used to position any `UIElement`: `<Canvas><Image x:Name="PositionedImage" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150" /></Canvas>`

Comment: **Pro Tip**, When asking a question, assume everyone doesn't know what you are talking about, and you are explaining it to someone that hasn't done this before and use as much information as you can to precisely describe your problem and what you want to do, over explain it if you must but in a reasonable about of words